# Image Matching on Android Game's Board

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

The question comes 1st: I am looking for **FAST** approach to match images.

Now, the use case: I am developing a detector to detect orb on a 6x5 Match-3 game board for android platform. I have an array of the orb icon with **transparent** background, but the orb on the screen (screenshot) has different background color, probably different size too. I have to compare each orb on the screen with my array of icons (69 icons specifically) so it's a 69x30=2070 steps. I tried lazy implementation and group almost similar icon together to reduce the steps but still take a long time (10s at most) for computation. I also tried checking the channel and depth of image, resizing the images to have same size and tweaking the threshold value but still no luck.

I have tried `Histogram Matching (seperate channel, grayscale)`, `Template Matching (CCOEFF, SQDIFF, CCORR)`, `AKAZE`, `ORB(unbounded, bounded)`, `PHash` all using OpenCV but histogram matching and PHash give me erroneous result (too much false positive), Template Matching consume 10s+ (considered too slow for user to wait) while AKAZE and ORB give better result than all other methods but still needs 6s+ per try. Is there any other method that can helps me cut down the computation time down to somewhere near 1s and can give better result considering the worst case scenario is 2070 steps?

Referrences that I have read that compares the performances of different feature matching algorithms:
[A comparative analysis of SIFT, SURF, KAZE, AKAZE, ORB, and BRISK](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323561586_A_comparative_analysis_of_SIFT_SURF_KAZE_AKAZE_ORB_and_BRISK). It shows that ORB and BRISK should be averagely better than the other approach compared while AKAZE is moderately good for most cases. I deleted my Histogram comparison code as it is not really helpful but you may find the rest of it below.

```
Mat source = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.orb_icon, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
Mat tmp = new Mat();
Bitmap cropped_img = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenshot, x, y, width, height);
Utils.bitmapToMat(cropped_img, tmp);

//template matching code
int r_rows = source.rows() - tmp.rows() + 1;
int r_cols = source.cols() - tmp.cols() + 1;
Mat result = new Mat();

result.create(r_rows, r_cols, CvType.CV_32F);

Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, tmp, result, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
double maxVal = mmr.maxVal;
return maxVal;

//AKAZE
MatOfKeyPoint kp1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
MatOfKeyPoint kp2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
Mat desc1 = new Mat();
Mat desc2 = new Mat();
AKAZE akaze = AKAZE.create();
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
akaze.detectAndCompute(source, new Mat(), kp1, desc1);
akaze.detectAndCompute(tmp, new Mat(), kp2, desc2);
List<MatOfDMatch> knnMatches = new ArrayList<>();
matcher.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, knnMatches, 2);

float threshold = 0.7f;
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<knnMatches.size(); i++) {
    if(knnMatches.get(i).rows() > 1) {
        DMatch[] matches = knnMatches.get(i).toArray();
        if(matches[0].distance < threshold * matches[1].distance) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

//ORB    
ORB orb = ORB.create();
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
MatOfKeyPoint kp1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
MatOfKeyPoint kp2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
Mat desc1 = new Mat();
Mat desc2 = new Mat();
orb.detectAndCompute(source, new Mat(), kp1, desc1);
orb.detectAndCompute(tmp, new Mat(), kp2, desc2);
List<MatOfDMatch> knnMatches = new ArrayList<>();
matcher.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, knnMatches, 2);

float threshold = 0.8f;
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<knnMatches.size(); i++) {
    if(knnMatches.get(i).rows() > 1) {
        DMatch[] matches = knnMatches.get(i).toArray();
        if(matches[0].distance < threshold * matches[1].distance) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

//PHash
Mat hash_source = new Mat();
Mat hash_tmp = new Mat();
Img_hash.pHash(tmp, hash_tmp);
Img_hash.pHash(source, hash_source);
Core.norm(source, tmp, Core.NORM_HAMMING);
```

Edit: As suggested, below is the game board, icon image, and orb screenshot sample.
[image: Game board]

ICON[image: orb icon] vs orb screenshot [image: orb screenshot]

Also, you may observe the simulation result of each approach by comparing the result(overlay smaller icon) on top of the orb on board:

Histogram Matching

[image: Histogram],

Template Matching

[image: Template Matching] and

AKAZE (similar to ORB)

[image: AKAZE and ORB]

After moving the variable initialization out of my comparison function to base class, detect keypoint and PHash of source icon images on class initialization, run detect and compute function in batch using List to reduce individual function call. It still takes up 4s+ for the image matching process. Time consumption is reduced but accuracy is still a major problem. You may observe my heap stack on below.

[image: Profiling output]

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to write C/C++ to remove the JNI overhead, but you should do a performance analysis to see if that is your bottleneck. If possible you may wish to include an image of your game board for others to understand your problem space.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for your quick reply, I have done a profiling on my app after some improvement on the code, but improvement is maxed out on 4s+. Does this means I have to port my comparison function to C++ as well to make it a single call on my main program? Also, is there any way how I can improve the accuracy of the matching? False positive cant be allowed in my use case.

Comment: Now that I see your game board, I'm impressed that you are trying to do game piece identification on an Android device. I would have gone with a PC/Server side solution and/or used an idealized match-3 game with simplified shapes, solid colors, and visually clean background. I'm also not sure if you looked at a Tensorflow based image matching. I can't tell anything from your heap image, you will have to make the choice about porting to C/C++. I would also check if OpenCV is properly parallelized, again don't know how you testing or on what devices. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know if you have tried this simplification: group possible matches first by color, then carry out the actual match method. For example: The first icon on your list will be tested for a match on your board. The color of the icon is red. So, filter out candidates on your board that are not red prior to matching. A little extra optimization: Try reducing the size of your board and your icons to speed up a little the matching process.

Comment: Are you matching over the whole image or do you segment the board first to get each orb seperately?